# Make available port 137 on Wine applications

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, proxy, wine

I am using Ubuntu 17.10 + Wine 2.18 (development version).

CCProxy is a proxy server for Windows. It is compatible with Wine, and [officially mentioned](http://www.youngzsoft.net/ccproxy/ccproxy-in-linux.htm).

I tried and run CCProxy in Wine, everything seems OK, but unfortunately one feature does not work... CCProxy cannot get client's MAC address for authentication. Also the solution to this problem is mentioned in [CCProxy's website](http://www.youngzsoft.net/ccproxy/faq_82.htm):

> CCProxy uses port 137 to get client's MAC address for authentication.
> So you need to make sure port 137 is available on both CCProxy server
> and client. Sometimes, antivirus software and firewall may block port
> 137, please check it out.
>
> On the other hand, you also need to install NetBIOS protocol on the client.

The problem is I don't know what to do, and what I supposed to do!

**Edit:**

```
$ sudo iptables -L

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wine should never be run as `root`.  Accordingly, ***no Wine applications should execute as `root` EVER***.  And most linux systems won't let non-root bind to ports lower than 1024.

If you want to run an application on a given port in Wine, you should always try and have it bind to a higher number port above 1024, which the system should permit you to bind to.  Then, set up `iptables` to do forwarding internally from port 137 to whichever port you've selected.

This said, the compatibility between Wine and the network card is such that it's a little limited - it has no guarantee that it'll actually be a fully compatible system where everything works.

Consider also that the post you reference is from 2015.  I can't find *anything* for this software on the WineHQ AppDB, and cannot even begin to fathom the number of issues you might have running this software.  (I may test later and try and see what happens, however I don't guarantee you'll get this software to work.)

---

***EDIT*** I did some further tests.  I was able to get CCProxy to run within Wine (in its own prefix), and properly work, but *only* with ports higher than 1024.  Also with additional testing, I was ***unable*** to get MAC address authentication working.

Therefore, based on my findings I don't think you'll be able to use MAC address based auth.  Is there a reason you can't use user/password authentication as your control mechanism, rather than MAC address auth?